# trying to get user assign to under another user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a sql query in which I want all the list of `uid` assigned under another `uid` from the below given table

```
uid rid assTo
1   1   NULL
2   2   1
3   1   2
6   11  3
7   11  1
17  11  1
18  11  1
19  11  1
21  11  1
22  2   1
23  11  22
24  2   22
25  10  24
26  10  24
27  11  26
28  11  26
29  10  24
30  11  3
31  11  29
32  11  29
33  11  29
34  11  29
35  11  29
36  11  29
37  11  29
38  11  29
39  11  29
40  11  29
41  11  29
47  11  2
48  11  2
50  11  26
51  11  2
52  11  26
53  11  29
55  11  1
56  11  1
57  11  652
68  11  652
70  11  652
71  11  652
72  11  2
74  1   1
75  11  2
76  11  652
80  11  652
86  11  652
87  11  1
88  11  26
89  11  29
```

I want all the list of `uid` assigned to another `uid` i.e. designated in `assto` column in above table

How can I implement it?

My query

```
select u1.assignto 'assignto',u2.userid 'userid'
from users u1 join users u2
on u1.assignto=u2.userid
```

My desired output is that when i search `uid = 1` 
i should the list of the `uid` available in the above table.

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: perform a `self join` to the table joining with assto column.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

`IN` solution:

```
select * from tablename
where uid in (select assTo from tablename)
```

Self `JOIN` solution:

```
select distinct t1.*
from tablename t1
  JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.uid= t2.assTo
```

`EXISTS` solution (similar to `IN`):

```
select *
from tablename t1
where exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.assTo = t1.uid)
```